# Dynamic store not loading data in combo box extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4

I have two combo boxes say combo 1 and combo 2 that get populated with two different stores (say store 1 and store 2). The value in combo2 depends on what is selected in combo 1. I then query the server to get the array for combo2. In other words, my selection in combo1 determines the values for combo2. 
The code I have set up is not working and gives me a very generic error `Error: Object doesn't support this action`. I see the return values in the browser debugger so I know its not my `ajax` request. I think I am missing something small in the combo box that keeps the values from displaying. Please see the code below to get a better idea

> ```
>    var store1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
>   model: 'store1model',
>   autoLoad: true,
>   autoDestroy: true,
>   proxy: {
>     type: 'ajax',
>     url: 'backend.java'
>     extraParams: {
>       'param1': param1
>     },
>     reader: {
>       type: 'json'
>     }
> ```

```
  }
});

var store2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
  model: 'store2model',
  autoLoad: true,
  autoDestroy: true,
  storeId: 'store2Id',
  proxy: 'memory',
  readre: {
    type: 'json'
  }
});

var panel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
  title: 'Panel',
  id: 'PanelId',
  url: 'backened.java',
  method: 'GET',
  items: [{
    xtype: container,
    layout: 'column',
    items: [{
      xtype: 'container',
      columnWidth: .5,
      layout: 'anchor',
      items: [{
        xtype: 'combobox',
        fieldLabel: 'Combo1',
        name: 'Combo1',
        store: store1,
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'name',
        anchor: '96%',
        listeners: {
          select: function(combo, records) {
            Ext.Ajax.request({
              url: 'backend.java',
              method: 'GET',
              params: {
                "param2": combo.getValue()
              },
              success: function(response) {
                var data = Ext.Msg.decode(response.responseText);
                store2.loadData(data);
              }
            });
          }
        }
      }, {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        fieldLabel: 'Combo2',
        name: 'Combo2',
        id: 'Combo2',
        store: store2,
        displayField: 'someField',
        valueField: 'someField'

      }]

    }]
  }]


});
```

After some searching I found may be I have to listen to event change in combo2. Not sure if that's correct and if it is how would that work? So I guess my question is two folds. Firstly, why wouldn't the above code work? Secondly, is there a better/more elegant way of doing this.

**EDIT**

```
 var store2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
   model: 'store2model',
   autoLoad: true,
   autoDestroy: true,
   storeId: 'store2Id',
    proxy: {
     type: 'ajax',
     url: 'backend.java'
   //  extraParams: {
     //  'param2': param2
    // },
     reader: {
       type: 'json'
     }

   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you assigned store1 a proxy so that you can do a store1.load(), maybe try doing the same with store2.

So you could assign the url 'backend.java' as a proxy to store2, and when combo1 gets selected, you can load the store for combo2 with the value is a param.

```
  {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        fieldLabel: 'Combo1',
        name: 'Combo1',
        store: store1,
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'name',
        anchor: '96%',
        listeners: {
          select: function(combo, records) {
            Ext.getCmp('Combo2').getStore().load({
                params: {
                  param2: combo.getValue()
                }
            });  
          }
        }
      },
```

That will load combo2's store with the param2 parameter.  So just assign combo2's store whatever the proxy url is.  Try that perhaps?

Comment: I tried that before but when I define the proxy for the store2 with `extraParams: {
      'param2': param2
    },` browser throws me an error saying `param2 is undefined`. That's why I did `Ajax.request` manually. Sorry may be I should have mentioned that in the question. Which makes sense because I haven't set `param2` yet.

Comment: I wouldn't declare the store with extra params.  Because at the time you declare the store that extra param isn't known yet.  Instead, try like I showed where you send the extra param in at time of loading.  Using the notation above.  Don't declare store2 with any extra params at all.  You don't have to declare the extra param to send one along with it at load time.

Comment: May be its my lack of understanding of `proxy` but when when I set up `store2` with proxy I never receive a response. Looking at the console it turns out the server is never receiving the parameter `param2`. Please see the edit for how I set up `store2`

Comment: Don't do autoLoad: true in your store2.  It should only load when you tell it to (after selecting a value in combo1).  If you use the code I gave you in the listener for combo1, it should load and send param2.  Make sure that everytime you select an item from combo1, that a request gets sent to the server.

Comment: I tried your code exactly and now combo2 gets stuck in loading. I think the server is not returning anything. I don't see the url in the console window either (under network I mean).

Comment: In the console window under networks I can see my url being sent back as something like `backend.java?_dc=<some#>&query=&` and it continues. I think it should be `backend.java?_dc=<some#>&query=&param2=`value from combo. Not sure why this is happening when in case of `param1` the url looks like `backend.java?_dc=<some#>&query=&param1=` whatever selection I had made.

Comment: I'm sorry I had a mistake in my original answer.  You need to wrap the param2 in a "params: { param2: 'whatever'}" within the load call.  Try it now.  I updated the answer.

Comment: That change got me the response back but combo2 still gets stuck in loading state. Not sure why

Comment: I don't know if it will fix your problem but you should change Ext.data.ArrayStore to Ext.data.DataStore.

Comment: No changing the ArrayStore to DataStore didn't make much difference but doing that did make me catch a typo in my model which fixed the loading issue. @MichaelWatson and Christophe thanks for your help!